# Ciabatte e pantofole

Tags: word-meaning, difference

Posso capire la differenza tra ciabatte e pantofole? 
Ieri la mia amica ha detto pantofole, ma erano scarpe da tennis. Ma il mio amico che ride sempre (ma è bravo) dice che le pantofole si usano in casa, non si usano per il tennis. Dice che "stare in pantofole" è come dire "stare a casa" o "non fare niente".

Cerco nei vocabolari "pantofole" e "ciabatte" e mi sembrano uguali, ma lui dice che pantofole e ciabatte sono diverse e le prime si usano in casa, mentre le ciabatte anche in spiaggia (ma non le pantofole). Un casino nella mia testa! Chi ha ragione?

Comment: Una piccola nota: in italiano non si dice *essere giusto* ma *avere ragione*.

Comment: Mi sono permesso di correggere un po' il testo, ma non credo di aver cambiato il senso.

Comment: "Pantofola" mi dà l'idea che sia più invernale, e di solito è di stoffa e chiusa, la ciabatta può essere aperta (es. ciabatte da spiaggia)

Comment: Grazie @DaG io scrivo, poi vedo le correzioni e imparo, ma italiano è difficile. Ma "erano scarpe da tennis"... anche oggi sono "da tennis"... scusa, non riesco di spiegare!

Answer (score 1):

In effetti c'è confusione. *pantofola* sul vocabolario Treccani
http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pantofola/ viene definita come
calzatura da riposo, usata in casa, che copre interamente il piede.
Però al fondo della pagina, cita *ciabatta* come sinonimo, e
alla voce *ciabatta* http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ciabatta/
dice che è una pantofola, e accenna al fatto che "portare scarpe
a ciabatta" significa eliminare la parte dietro il tallone. Non si
capisce se il tallone faccia parte del piede; comunque non chiarisce le idee.

L'idea della gente è varia, come si evince dalle
risposte di Yahoo answers: https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080401071609AAIEw2f dove tutto sommato alcune risposte spiegano bene una probabile
differenza. Ci sono diversi altri siti con opinioni "minestrone",
come https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ciabatte.2110901/

Wikipedia, proprio all'inizio della descrizione, chiarisce che
c'è differenza, "La pantofola è una calzatura da casa. Differisce dalla ciabatta
perché è chiusa e da una scarpa per l'uso e i materiali." (https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantofola).

Su un glossario di artigianato (https://www.artimondo.it/magazine/pantofola-glossario-artigianato/)
di nuovo si dice, al fondo, che "la pantofola è chiusa, la ciabatta è aperta e sono anche fatte di materiali diversi"
(https://www.artimondo.it/magazine/pantofola-glossario-artigianato/)

D'altra parte il verbo *ciabattare*, *camminare strascicando ... rumore fastidioso*
(https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=ciabattare) rafforza l'idea che una
ciabatta non sia morbida e soprattutto non abbia laccio o copertura posteriori
così da impedire di sollevare bene per non fare rumore camminando o correndo.

La mia idea personale è che la pantofola sia chiusa, morbida e calda, la ciabatta aperta, rigida e non calda;
inoltre ritengo che sia sbagliato chiamare pantofole le scarpe da tennis anche se, chiuse e morbide,
ci assomigliano; in particolare, di solito, le pantofole non hanno lacci, mentre le scarpe da tennis / da ginnastica
sì.

Comment: Mi sembra che le tre voci del Treccani (è citata anche la pianella) siano chiare. Dicono, riducendo ai tratti essenziali: una pantofola è come una pianella ma è chiusa dietro (inversamente, una pianella è come una pantofola ma è aperta dietro), mentre “ciabatta” è un termine più generale (un iperonimo) che include sia la pantofola che la pianella.

Comment: (La Wikipedia in generale la lascerei perdere, soprattutto le voci senza fonti. Per esempio spesso ho trovato voci tradotte a orecchio dall'inglese, che cercavano di mantenere in italiano definizioni o distinzioni che valgono in inglese ma insensate in italiano.)

Comment: @dag non sono d'accordo col Treccani: li da' per sinonimi ma non lo sono; se ciabatta è un iperonimo (lo dici tu) allora ancor più non sono sinonimi. Wikipedia a volte sbaglia, come tutti, ma secondo me non in questo caso.

Comment: Non lo dico io che “ciabatta” sia un iperonimo, lo dice il Treccani (“Pianella, pantofola”). E comunque fra il Treccani + la mia conoscenza della mia lingua e linuxfan, mi fido più dei primi due, perdonami. :)

Comment: @dag fidarti di me? Che c'entro io? State facendo tutto da voi - tu e il Treccani: Treccani dice che A e B sono sinonimi, tu dici che uno è iperonimo dell'altro, vi contraddicete. E' il Treccani, nei sinonimi, che qualifica "ciabatta" come "scarpa col solo tomaio davanti". Dovrei dedurre che "pantofola", essendo sinonimo, ha solo la tomaia davanti? Tu deduci quello che ti pare, ma non tirare me in ballo.

Comment: Grazie di tanta informazione, la ultima frase è più utile, le frasi prima ripetono cose e serve tanto tempo a leggere e capire.

Comment: Ho letto le tre voci del Treccani e sono d'accordo che dicono quello che ha scritto @DaG nei suoi commenti. Se poi questo è veramente l'uso di questi tre termini che state facendo voi italiani, questo veramente non lo so.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Se ti riferisci ai “Sinonimi e contrari” del Treccani, ti ricordo che non registra solo i sinonimi puri, ammesso che esistano mai, ma appunto anche parole affini, iponimi e iperonimi (segnalandolo con simboli, come ≈ e ↑), perché lo scopo è aiutare a aiutare nella ricerca della parola più adatta, non dare equivalenze precise.